# How to get data from mixed tables (* join) via ObjectManager Interface?

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, entitymanager

I am building zf2 project and using Doctrine 2 in it.

I have 2 tables: News and Categories.

News is:

```
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ id + category_id + title + text + created +
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

Categories is:

```
+++++++++++++
+ id + name +
+++++++++++++
```

Contents of Categories is:

```
0 temp
1 cars
2 cows
3 casinos
```

Now I am working with news table like this:

```
$news = $objectManager
    ->getRepository('\News\Entity\NewsItem')
    ->findBy(array(), array('created' => 'DESC'));
```

I am retrieving something like this now:

```
1 0 1232 123d datetime
2 1 1234 1235 datetime
3 2 1236 6123 datetime
4 0 1233 1233 datetime
```

I want to get this:

```
1 temp 1232 123d datetime
2 cars 1234 1235 datetime
3 cows 1236 6123 datetime
4 temp 1233 1233 datetime
```

How I can get this data?

So, I need same behaviour of the code as SQL query behaviour with `JOIN` has.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suggest start reading the Doctrine Documentation.

Comment: @Sam I tried it! But it is soooo hard ! :D Is [this](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-one-unidirectional) is what I need? How this will look? 2 classes (2 models)? Ok. But question is still open. How I can get output as I want. I am very new to Doctrine so it is hard for me to find exactly what I need because I don't know how this method is called. Any other suggestions? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Check this one out: https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineModule/blob/master/docs/hydrator.md#a-complete-example-using-zendform

Comment: @Sam thank you! Am I right that relationships between Tags and BlogPosts is this: Tags 1 - Many BlogPosts. That means, that 1 blogpost can contain many tags, right? + I found [this](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/working-with-objects.html#custom-repositories) — Custom Repositories. Using DQL I can include other models, like simple Tables in SQL, right?

Comment: @Sam I think in your example, it will create 3 tables. For tags, for blogpost and table, connecting 2 this tables. Am I right?

Comment: @Sam Can you look this files: [NewsItem.php](https://github.com/sharikovvladislav/my-zf2-project/blob/developing/module/News/src/News/Entity/NewsItem.php) and [Category.php](https://github.com/sharikovvladislav/my-zf2-project/blob/developing/module/News/src/News/Entity/Category.php). This is 2 models in `News` module. I tried to link them (47-50 lines of file `ItemNews.php`), updated schema, but it just created new table `Category` without altering `News` table and adding foreign key to it. Why?